# I am trying to get code to work that decodes and displays a raw H264 tcp/ip video stream. Can someone diagnose what is wrong?

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

My goal is to play a raw H264 stream being fed through a tcp/ip port on an Android device (a Samsung S10) using the MediaCodec class.  It isn't working, I just see a blank screen.

I have a few guesses to the issue: 1) Do I need to group together NAL units?  Right now I feed each unit individually to the MediaCodec. 2) Do I need to make changes to the server? are there variants of H264 that the MediaCodec class cannot handle?

I was able to port FFmpeg to Android studio and got this solution to work.  However, it is slow as it uses a software codec.  I decided to use MediaCodec to try and use the hardware codec.  The code below shows my effort.  The codec is initialized in asynchronous mode.  I have a separate thread to read and queue up the NAL frames from the tcp socket.  Frames are stored in a buffer and if the buffer overflows, then some frames will be discarded.  The onInputBufferAvailable codec feeds one NAL unit at a time to the MediaCodec class.

```java
    public void initializePlaybackCodec()
    {
        mWidth = 1536;
        mHeight = 864;
        MediaFormat decoderFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);
        try {
            codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "CODEC INIT: Failed to initialize media codec", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to initialize media codec",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        Log.i(TAG,"HERE CODEC INITIALIZED");

        final int videoQueueSize = 10;
        final Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
        final Semaphore queueData = new Semaphore(0);
        final ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>(videoQueueSize);
        codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {
            long reference_epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long current_epoch = reference_epoch;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            int nextStart = 0;

            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
                current_epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();

                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);

                android.media.MediaCodecInfo info = codec.getCodecInfo();
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: info "+info.getName()+" Encoder: "+info.isEncoder()+" ");
                //String[] types = info.getSupportedTypes();
                //for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                //    Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: supportedType "+types[j]);
                //}
                // Read data from the Queue
                ByteBuffer b = null;
                Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: input");
                try {
                    queueData.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CODEC CALLBACK: queueData acquire interrupted");
                    codec.stop();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    mutex.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CODEC CALLBACK: mutex acquire interrupted");
                    codec.stop();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    b = queue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "CODEC CALLBACK: take interrupted");
                    codec.stop();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
                byte[] bb = b.array();
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: Contents being sent "+bb[4]/32+" "+bb[4]%32+" "+bb.length);
                Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: Contents being sent "+Integer.toHexString(bb[0])+" "+Integer.toHexString(bb[1])+" "+Integer.toHexString(bb[2])+" "+Integer.toHexString(bb[3])+" "+Integer.toHexString(bb[4])+" ");
                int ref_idc = bb[4]/32;
                int unit_type = bb[4]%32;
                //for (int i = 0; i < bb.length && i < 5; ++i) {
                //    Log.i(TAG, "CODEC CALLBACK: bb["+i+"]="+bb[i]);
                //}

                mutex.release();
                // fill inputBuffer with valid data
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: put "+b.remaining()+" "+b.capacity());
                inputBuffer.clear();
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: before put "+inputBuffer.remaining()+" "+b.position());
                b.position(0);
                inputBuffer.put(b);
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: after put "+inputBuffer.remaining());
                //Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: queue "+(current_epoch-reference_epoch)*1000+" "+inputBuffer.capacity()+" "+inputBuffer.remaining());

                codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId,0, b.remaining(), (current_epoch-reference_epoch)*1000, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId,
                                                MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);
                MediaFormat bufferFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(outputBufferId); // option A
                // bufferFormat is equivalent to mOutputFormat
                // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.
                Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: output");

                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, true);

                Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: output done");
            }

            @Override
            public void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec mc, MediaFormat format) {
                // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
                // Can ignore if using getOutputFormat(outputBufferId)
                //mOutputFormat = format; // option B
                Log.i(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: output format changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(MediaCodec codec, MediaCodec.CodecException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"CODEC CALLBACK: Media Codec Error");
            }
        });
        codec.configure(decoderFormat, m_surface.getHolder().getSurface(), null,  0);

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Socket socket;
                InputStream input;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(mServerAddr, Integer.parseInt(mServerPort));
                    input = socket.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: Failed to open video socket", e);
                    Toast.makeText(ARActivity.this, "Failed to open video socket",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: HERE SOCKET OPENED");
                System.out.println("Socket opened");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
                java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBuffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(blockSize);
                int nextStart = 0;
                while (true) {
                    int size = 1;
                    try {
                        size = input.read(buffer,nextStart,blockSize-nextStart);
                        Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: Read from video stream "+size+" bytes start="+nextStart);
                        Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: First bytes "+buffer[nextStart]+" "+buffer[nextStart+1]+" "+
                                buffer[nextStart+2]+" "+buffer[nextStart+3]+" "+buffer[nextStart+4]);
                        if (size==0) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: Video stream finished");
                            Toast.makeText(ARActivity.this, "Video stream finished",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            codec.stop();
                            finish();
                            return;
                        }
                        int endPos = 2;
                        while (endPos > 0) {
                            endPos = -1;
                            int zeroCount = 0;
                            for (int i = nextStart; (i < size+nextStart && endPos < 1); ++i) {
                                //Log.i(TAG,"Zero count pos "+i+" "+zeroCount);
                                if (buffer[i]==0) {
                                    ++zeroCount;
                                } else if (buffer[i]==1 && zeroCount > 1) {
                                    if (zeroCount > 3) {
                                        zeroCount = 3;
                                    }
                                    endPos = i-zeroCount;
                                    Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: Found marker at pos "+(i-zeroCount));
                                    zeroCount = 0;
                                } else {
                                    zeroCount = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: State nextStart="+nextStart+" endPos="+endPos+" size="+size);
                            if (endPos < 0) {
                                if (size + nextStart == blockSize) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: Error reading video stream2");
                                    //Toast.makeText(ARActivity.this, "Error reading video stream2",
                                    //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    //finish();
                                    endPos = blockSize;
                                    nextStart = 0;
                                    Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: BLOCK OVERFLOW " + endPos);
                                } else {
                                    nextStart = size + nextStart;
                                }
                            } else if (endPos==0) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: BLOCK NOT COMPLETE " + endPos);
                                //nextStart = size+nextStart;
                            } else {
                                Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: PROCESSING BLOCK " + endPos);
                                //Log.i(TAG,"BUFFER REMAINING "+byteBuffer.remaining());
                                //Log.i(TAG,"BUFFER POSITION "+byteBuffer.position());
                                //System.arraycopy(buffer, 4, buffer, 0, size + nextStart - 4);
                                //nextStart = nextStart - 4;
                                //if (nextStart < 0) {
                                //    size = size + nextStart;
                                //    nextStart = 0;
                                //}
                                //endPos = endPos-4;
                                byteBuffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(endPos+3);
                                byteBuffer.put(buffer, 0, endPos);
                                //byteBuffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, endPos);
                                //byteBuffer.put(buffer,0, endPos);
                                Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: BUFFER REMAINING2 " + byteBuffer.remaining());
                                Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: BUFFER POSITION2 " + byteBuffer.position());
                                Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: First send bytes " + buffer[0] + " " + buffer[1] + " " +
                                        buffer[2] + " " + buffer[3] + " " + buffer[4]);
                                //byte[] bb = byteBuffer.array();
                                Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: Contents being sent");

                                //for (int i = 0; i < bb.length && i < 10; ++i) {
                                //    Log.i(TAG, "RLOOP: bb["+i+"]="+bb[i]);
                                //}
                                try {
                                    mutex.acquire();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: Mutex interrupted");
                                    codec.stop();
                                    finish();
                                    return;
                                }
                                Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: HERE1");
                                if (queue.size() == videoQueueSize) {
                                    try {
                                        queue.take();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: queue.take interrupted 2");
                                        codec.stop();
                                        finish();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: HERE2");
                                    try {
                                        queueData.acquire();
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: queueData.acquire() interrupted 2");
                                        codec.stop();
                                        finish();
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                Log.i(TAG,"RLOOP: HERE3");
                                try {
                                    queue.put(byteBuffer);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: queue put interrupted");
                                    codec.stop();
                                    finish();
                                    return;
                                }
                                queueData.release();
                                mutex.release();
                                if (endPos < size+nextStart) {
                                    System.arraycopy(buffer, endPos, buffer, 0, size + nextStart - endPos);
                                    nextStart = nextStart - endPos;
                                    if (nextStart < 0) {
                                        size = size + nextStart;
                                        nextStart = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        nextStart = nextStart + size;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "RLOOP: Error reading from video stream");
                        Toast.makeText(ARActivity.this, "Error reading from video stream",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        codec.stop();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
        codec.start();

        return;


    }
```

My expected result is to see a video on the android device.  My actual result is that the onOutputBufferAvailable function is never called.

I am including a sample debugging output to show some of the NAL units being sent to the MediaCodec class.

```
2019-06-19 12:22:38.229 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: input
2019-06-19 12:22:38.249 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: Contents being sent 0 0 0 1 61
2019-06-19 12:22:38.251 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: input
2019-06-19 12:22:38.266 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: Contents being sent 0 0 0 1 61
2019-06-19 12:22:38.268 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: input
2019-06-19 12:22:38.281 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: Contents being sent 0 0 0 1 61
2019-06-19 12:22:38.282 3325-3539/com.example.unrealar I/MediaCodec: setCodecState state : 0
2019-06-19 12:22:38.282 3325-3325/com.example.unrealar I/ARActivity: CODEC CALLBACK: input
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't see you configuring the Codec. With that i mean sending `SPS` and `PPS` with flag `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG`.

> Such data [CSD] must be marked using the flag `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` in a call to `queueInputBuffer`

[it's documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#CSD).

There are many ways of transferring H264. The most common ones (at least to me i guess) are:

- At the beginning of the stream and every time the encoding parameters change.
- With every NALU. Every NALU carries it's own set of CSD. You only need to reconfigure if the values change.
- `SPS` and `PPS` before each key frame and `PPS` before other slices. [It is called AnnexB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682275/h264-with-multiple-pps-and-sps)

As FFMPEG was able to decode the stream, i'd guess that these values are part of the stream.
So i guess you need to parse your H264 stream to determine the SPS and PPS and send a buffer with these values and the `BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG` to the decoder.
Or if you decide buffer some frames at the begining, before you start decoding, you could also put these values inside your `MediaFormat` as `"csd-0" (SPS)` and `"csd-1" (PPS)`

- `SPS` start with the NALU sequence `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x67`.
- `PPS` start with the NALU sequence `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x68`.