# How to fix corrupted video (green frames) after muxing using MediaMuxer and MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, video-processing, mediamuxer

I am trying to encode an mp4 video from an array of NalUnits where each unit is a frame represented by byte[] that is saved from an rtp packet from an rtsp stream. I am encoding 451 frames at a 30fps where the first frame data is the spp and pps frame combined. This is my current configuration:

```
Width: 720
Height: 480
Bitrate: 10_000_000
Fps: 30
Colorformat: COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible
Key I Frame Interval: 1
```

Here is my method where I encode the configure the encoder:

```
public boolean createMp4Video(FrameQueue.Frame[] frames, File dir) {
    try {
        // Set up MediaMuxer
        Date date = new Date();
        File file = new File(dir, date + "-recording.mp4");
        this.muxer = new MediaMuxer(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        // Set up MediaCodec
        mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(codecName, width, height);
        mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
        mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, framerate);
        mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);

        codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(codecName);
        codec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

        codec.start();

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        // Process frames
        for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
            if (i == frames.length - 1) { // if last frame, add end of stream flag
                muxFrame(frames[i].getData(), i, true);
            } else {
                muxFrame(frames[i].getData()), i, false);                     
        }

            // Stop and release resources
            muxer.stop();
            muxer.release();
            codec.stop();
            codec.release();
            listener.onMp4VideoCreated();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I loop through all the frames using a simple for loop and call the following function to method:

```
private void muxFrame(byte[] frameData, int encodeIndex, boolean isVideoEOS) {
    long presentationTimeUs = 1000000 / framerate * encodeIndex

    int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
        inputBuffer.put(frameData);
        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, frameData.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
    }

    // Create a MediaCodec.BufferInfo to hold the frame information
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo muxerOutputBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(muxerOutputBufferInfo, 1000);

    switch (outputBufferIndex) {
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
            MediaFormat newFormat = codec.getOutputFormat();
            mVideoTrack = muxer.addTrack(newFormat);
            muxer.start();
            break;
        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
            break;
        default:
            // Set the size, presentation time, and flags of the muxerOutputBufferInfo
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.size = frameData.length;
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.offset = 0;
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.flags = isVideoEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs;
            // Write the frame data to the muxer
            muxer.writeSampleData(mVideoTrack, ByteBuffer.wrap(frameData), muxerOutputBufferInfo);
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            break;
    }


}
```

I am able to save the video and play it but all the frames are corrupted and green as such https://dropmefiles.com/rn6I0

Here is my log when I am encoding:

```
I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained
W/OMXUtils: do not know color format 0x7f000200 = 2130706944
W/OMXUtils: do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
I/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] using color format 0x7f420888 in place of 0x7f420888
I/ACodec_vilte: set I frame rate
I/ACodec_vilte: set framerate
I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, width: 720
I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, height: 480
I/ACodec: setupAVCEncoderParameters with [profile: Baseline] [level: Level41]
I/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring.
I/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] cannot encode HDR static metadata. Ignoring.
I/ACodec: setupVideoEncoder succeeded
I/ACodec_vilte: set I frame rate
I/ACodec_vilte: set framerate
I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, width: 720
I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, height: 480
I/general: [33] Configuring video encoder - 450 frames
I/general: [33] Video encoding in progress
D/MPEG4Writer: start+ 797
I/MPEG4Writer: limits: 4294967295/0 bytes/us, bit rate: -1 bps and the estimated moov size 3191 bytes
D/MPEG4Writer: start+ 2403
D/MPEG4Writer: start- 2481
D/MPEG4Writer: start- 964
I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 166665
I/MPEG4Writer: Earliest track starting time: 166665
D/MPEG4Writer: Video mStartTimestampUs=166665us
D/MPEG4Writer: reset+ 1081
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping. Stop source
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopping
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track source stopped
I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (439/0) buffers and encoded 439 frames. - Video
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopped. Stop source
D/MPEG4Writer: Stopping writer thread
D/MPEG4Writer: 0 chunks are written in the last batch
D/MPEG4Writer: Writer thread stopped
I/MPEG4Writer: Ajust the moov start time from 166665 us -> 166665 us
I/MPEG4Writer: The mp4 file will not be streamable.
D/MPEG4Writer: reset- 1187
D/MPEG4Writer: reset+ 1081
D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping. Stop source
I/general: [33] MP4 video created successfully
```

Comment: I see. The bytes works well with a surface view. I am able to stream the video. However, only when I am trying to encode the bytedata the frames are corrupted. Here is a link to the output video https://dropmefiles.com/yfqad

Comment: @VC.One Can you please help with this?

Comment: Your **SPS** and **PPS** is wrong. Your code says it makes a 1280x720 frame but your file has 640x600 frame, and the input from array of NAL units might itself be yet another different frame resolution... The fastest way to know your expected settings is to check. **(1)** If your NAL units all start with an Annex-B **start code** like `00 00 01` then just concat them into one long array, and save as an H264 file to test with VLC media player. **(2)** If you don't have start codes, then you need to show how your input is structured (you might have to remove some extra bytes to reach video data)

Comment: These are my SPS and PPS bytes combined in one array. `[0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 66, 0, 41, -30, -112, 22, -121, -74, 6, -84, 24, 4, 27, -121, -119, 17, 80, 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -50, 60, -128]`
Do I need to encode these as well?

Comment: All my frames starts with`0 0 0 1` which is why I am using stripNALUnitStartCode. Do we need this information while endoing or should I strip this data from my frames?

Comment: I fixed the file, the video is now encoded in 1280x720. The frames are still corrupted can you please have a quick look if there is something wrong . Here is the file with a screenshot of the code info https://dropmefiles.com/w9LC3

Comment: I have added the requested information in my post. For some reason the first NalUnit after the sps and pps is only 30 length compared to the other nalunits and NalUnit1 and NalUnit2 have timestamps have identical values is this normal?

Comment: @VC.One https://dropmefiles.com/Cewey I have added the new raw bytes[] file with NALUNIT1 and NALUNIT2. The file is around 13kb. Also, added a new version of the recording. If you caould please check.

Comment: I have refactored my code and updated my post with the current encoding method and output log if you can please have a look. I tried everything, not sure if it is a hardware issue where writing speed comes into play or not

Comment: I did so, removed the first spspps and changed the resolution to 720*480. Still no results :( when you have time if you can check the configuration that I have added in the post perhaps there is something off

Comment: It's coming together. I dropped the encoding stuff and now I have some frames that are visible but the video is still corrupted.  I have updated my code and uploaded the new video and raw bytes files here - https://dropmefiles.com/rn6I0

Can you please have a look

Comment: After reading this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686267/17121708 I finally I fixed it by adding the combined sps+pps frame that is captured at the start of the stream before each nalunit frame. Thanks a lot for the help I would love to buy you a cofee for helping me troubleshoot this!

Comment: Yes If you want I  think you will provide a better explanation with your answer and I will mark it as solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the video have corrupted frames?** From a look at the [shared bytes](https://dropmefiles.com/rn6I0):

**1) Every frame is a Key-frame**  
I wondered why your MP4's section for listing keyframes, the `stss` atom, had **every single frame** listed as a type "Key-frame" (why no P-frames and B-frames?) but then I see that your code has this command:

```
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
```

Since you are **muxing** (copy/pasting existing media bytes), that **media has its own interval** which should be written into the output MP4... A Muxing process does not need to be given a new keyframe interval.

**solution:** 
Test a possible fix of disabling (or comment `//`) that line, 
With same `//` disabling of the `bitrate` setting.

**2) Your first frame is not a keyframe**
The first video frame that you send to the muxer is not a keyframe. 
It is marked as a key-frame in the MP4 metadata (at the **stss** atom) but it's actual bytes are of type P-frame. This means: After **start-code** `0, 0, 0, 1` your NAL header is found to be hex: `42`, or decimal: `65`). Be aware because a decimal `65` is not same as hex `65` and so it can be confusing, if you forget to convert, and think that decimal `65` means this NALU is a keyframe.

**solution:** 
Make sure you send a NAL unit with decimals: `0, 0, 0, 1, 101` (or in hex: `00, 00, 00, 01, 65`).

The `101` marks it as a keyframe NALU (header byte value is: `0x65` or as decimal value: `101`).

**3) You have wrong SPS and PPS** 
Once again the problem is a wrong SPS and PPS... 
Inside the MP4, the SPS/PPS data goes into the **avcC** section (which holds the "AVC configuration", and AVC is just an alternate name for H264).

If I manually overwrite a part of the `avcC` section by copy/pasting over the bytes from the raw NALUs then your corrupt MP4 shows a perfect picture (not messy colours).

**solution:**

**option A:** Try to set a `MediaFormat` with the SPS and PPS included. 
This means putting an entry for [Codec-Specfic Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#CSD) according to these **keys**:

```
Format      CSD buffer #0                       CSD buffer #1                       CSD buffer #2
H.264 AVC   SPS (Sequence Parameter Sets)       PPS (Picture Parameter Sets)        Not Used
```

**option B:** In a worst case scenario you might have to manually fix the bytes after the MP4 file is created by your Android code (*eg:* after the file creation code finishes, run another function which finds and overwrites some circa 25 bytes of existing SPS & PPS inside the newly created MP4). Hopefully not needed as a solution.

I cannot test Android code, please check if this example code creates a working MP4:

**(1)** Converting between Decimals into Hex (since bytes are written as hex)

```
//# check Byte as Decimal
int temp_int = (NALU_SPS[4] & 0xFF); //where NALU_SPS is an Array.
System.out.println("NALU Decimal: " + temp_int );

//# check Byte as Hex
String temp_str = Integer.toString( temp_int, 16 );
temp_str = (temp_str.length() < 2) ? ("0"+temp_str) : temp_str;
System.out.println("NALU Byte: 0x" + temp_str );
```

Use the above to convert your Array values when double-checking their byte value, since tutorials and H264 Specification will mention the byte values in a Hex format.

A byte example like `0xFF` is hex `FF` and is decimal `255`.

**(2)** Try this `MediaFormat` setup.

```
//# Set up MediaCodec
mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(codecName, width, height);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, framerate);

//# Your SPS/PPS in an Array. Can be: byte[] ...or Else: int[]
byte[] NALU_SPS = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00, 0x29, 0xE2, 0x90, 0x16, 0x87, 0xB6, 0x06, 0xAC, 0x18, 0x04, 0x1B, 0x87, 0x89, 0x11, 0x50 };
byte[] NALU_PPS = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xCE, 0x3C, 0x80 };

//# send SPS/PPS to the Muxer
mMediaFormat.setByteBuffer( "csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap( NALU_SPS ) );
mMediaFormat.setByteBuffer( "csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap( NALU_PPS ) );

//# This might not be needed (since Muxer could get from SPS/PPS)
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);

//# test with these disabled
//mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate);
//mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
```

Comment: From analyzing your raw files you can try these settings: `MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 32);` and also `MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1339000` (raw has **1339 Kilo-bits/sec** of bitrate) ... Now do you get a playable file (without needing to prefix the SPS/PPS before each frame)?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not use MediaMuxer because it seems to produce wrong output. use mp4v2 library instead, it will produce the correct output and work consistently across all devices.

Comment: Does this library you mentioned exist for android?

Comment: It's a C++ library, you can add it as a library to your app. It uses CMake which makes it easier to integrate with Android build system.